# MongoDB update of multiple documents using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following data with mongodb:

```
    IdsUniques = [
         '4534ferwr342342dfw42',
         'f34523sfdf34r2342323',
         '435342e2wr23423dew2e'
    ],
    IdsMulti = [
         '4534ferwr342342dfw42',
         'f34523sfdf34r2342323',
         '435342e2wr23423dew2e'
    ],
    IdsBlank = [];
```

I want to update separate objectId data with this array like:

```
db.collection.update({_id: {$in: [obj1, obj2, obj3]}, 
                     {$pushAll: [IdsUniques, IdsMulti, IdsBlank]})
```

i want result as insert record to the 
obj1 as IdsUniques
obj2 as IdsMulti
obj3 as IdsBlank

Example like following (if it's possible then ):-

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId(1),
  IdsUniques: [
             '4534ferwr342342dfw42',
             'f34523sfdf34r2342323',
             '435342e2wr23423dew2e'
        ]
},
{ 
  _id: ObjectId(2),
  IdsMulti: [
             '4534ferwr342342dfw42',
             'f34523sfdf34r2342323',
             '435342e2wr23423dew2e'
        ]
},
{
  _id: ObjectId(3),
  IdsBlank: []
}
```

Comment: That would need to be 3 separate updates.

Comment: Yes, it's true,
but will be done ? with only one update query.